# Formatting poetry

Tags: support

What's the best way to format poetry, where preserving line breaks is important, but extra white space is not desired between lines?

I encountered the situation for [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/94072/17165) and was not impressed with the look of formatting that resulted from my use of a blockquote, i.e., like this:

> As dry leaves before the wild hurricane fly,
>
> When they meet with an obstacle, mount to the sky;
>
> So up to the house-top the coursers they flew,
>
> With the sleigh full of toys — and St. Nicholas too:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put two spaces at the end of each line in the blockquote, and don't put a blank line between lines of text. The result looks like this:

> As dry leaves before the wild hurricane fly,
>   When they meet with an obstacle, mount to the sky;
>   So up to the house-top the coursers they flew,
>   With the sleigh full of toys — and St. Nicholas too:

Comment: Thank you. That's helpful for me, too. I wish there were some way to use numbered items with intervening paragraphs without getting everything renumbered to _1._

Comment: @John Put a space in front of the intervening paragraphs. That associates the paragraph with the previous numbered items so that subsequent numbered items continue the numbering.