# Should I vote up or down if I think the topic is important but I disagree with the proposal on meta?

Tags: discussion

I'm conflicted on a question of voting on meta questions. The original question is a significant and important topic, but I disagree with the proposal.

The example that caused the conflict (but there will be many other examples) is ["Formatting poetry"](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/formatting-poetry)

I think the topic is significant and worth discussion but I hold the opposite opinion to Edward Brayn on this specific issue.

So, on meta, what way should I vote?

Comment: Hi @Carlo_R - looks like you've been away for a while tending to your nascent Italian SO site! On that particular example, the OP did explicitly ask *What's the best way to format poetry?* It was really a bit of an aside that he said he "was not impressed" with one particular style, but if I were you I'd upvote the question *for the fact of being asked*. I see your point though - with some questions it's far more difficult. Sometimes I just post an answer precisely because of that ambiguity (I upvote this simply because it's a good question! :)

Comment: In this particular case I don't think OP is asking how poetry *should* be formatted but *how* to format poetry in the manner he defines, *videlicet* without leading. That, at any rate, is how Edward Brey appears to have taken it, and OP did not dissent. So in my opinion, your vote expresses your evaluation of the question, not OP's preference. But if you feel the question of how poetry should be formatted *is* in play I think you should present an alternative answer explaining why you prefer a different format.

Comment: @StoneyB: That's three things I owe you for in one day. I've now got a hat (Robin Day bowtie, actually), my own avatar (swiped from God knows where), and after reading Edward's answer prompted by your comment, I know know how to control linespacing in blockquotes (which really bugged me on [this answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/94887/2637)). ty ty ty!

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I tried that one and it made me look even nerdier, but it looks good on your avatar - very Christmas-y.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You actually don't need all the metacharacters used in that blockquote: One > on the first line suffices to blockquote an entire paragraph.

Comment: @MετάEd: Ages ago I tried without success to find a single page somewhere on SO that would set out definitively exactly what markup syntax was supported. [This](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74999/) is the best I could come up with, but unless it's badly laid out or I'm thick, it says nothing about the specific point we're dealing with here.

Answer (score 2):

The question you are referring is asking how to format poetry, and the answer is suggesting how to format poetry.

If you think the topic is important, then you would probably up-vote the question; if you disagree with the proposed way to format poetry, you would probably down-vote the answer.